# Can $(x\boxplus y)\oplus(x'\boxplus y')$ be simplified further?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$(x\boxplus y)\oplus(x'\boxplus y')$, where $\boxplus$ means additions which are done modulo $2^n$ and $\oplus$ means XOR. Can this be simplified further?
For example, $(x+y)*(x'+y')=x*(x'+y')+y*(x'+y')=x*x'+x*y'+y*x'+y*y'$. Does the formula above have some properties like this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$

Comment: @M. Di $x$ and $y$ are both a $n$-bit variable.

Comment: I see no compatibility rules between these two operators. And whithout compatibility (like distributivity in the case of $+$ and $\times$). You cant do simplification. The only possiblity would be to add another operator like AND.

Comment: @M. Di Thanks for your answer!